# Oracle Service Bus and MQ - connecting without setting the context data

Tags: ibm-mq, oracle-service-bus

I am using MQ Transport on the Oracle Service Bus to connect to external MQ server. The problem, however, is that the external MQ server cannot have any authority records other than:

- CONNECT/INQUIRE (for Queue Manager)
- PUT/GET/INQUIRE (for Queue)

This is a problem, because the OSB MQ Transport is always trying to connect with a context, and also put message with context as well. Even when I set up the MQC.MQPMO_NO_CONTEXT on the PUT message options, in the business service settings.

Is it even possible to exchange the messages with MQ, using the OSB MQ Transport and not having SET/SETALL authority records set?

PS. The MQ logs the following errors:

> AMQ8077: Entity 'osbtest     ' has insufficient authority to access
>   object 'TESTQMGR'.
>
> EXPLANATION: The specified entity is not authorized to access the
>   required object. The following requested permissions are unauthorized:
>   setall
>
> // ...
>
> AMQ8077: Entity 'osbtest     ' has insufficient authority to access
>   object 'TEST.QUEUE'.
>
> EXPLANATION: The specified entity is not authorized to access the
>   required object. The following requested permissions are unauthorized:
>   set

Versions:

- Oracle Service Bus: 11gR1
- Websphere MQ: 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an environment variable on the MQ server host named "MQSNOAUT" and setting its  to "YES"

Comment: I do. I now realise however that this is relevent only upon creating the Queue manager - [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc%2Fcs12405_.htm). Read the following link to see how to disable OAM - [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa13160_.htm).